# Safari will spontaneously visit URL while I type

Tags: safari

On my old MacBook Air and even on my brand new Retina MacBook Pro (which was set up as a new computer), if I open a new tab and quickly start typing a URL or search in the bar, Safari will sometimes truncate whatever it is I was typing and act as if I had pressed Return.

I believe this has something to do with the search suggestions/seek time for bookmarks but it happens stochastically so I can't determine the root cause.

Comment: is it possible that you unknowingly hit the return? I do that sometimes, and generate lots of typos :)

Comment: try this and remap your keyboard (just temporary) and reassign the return key to test the theory above :)  http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It just happened again. It corresponds precisely with the lag in smart search (history/bookmark autocomplete + google search suggestions). 

I definitely did not press Return.

Comment: I have the same problem! Even I thought it was just me accidentally hitting return, but I have a mechanical keyboard, so it can't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you:

1. have enabled Google as your default search engine
2. have enabled [Google Instant](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/instant/about.html) within your Google search settings

I have this same situation occur on my Chrome.

Comment: I've decided to disable Google Instant from Safari; this is done within Safari Preferences through the tab "Privacy". The last checkbox says "Prevent search engine from providing suggestions".